# Pagination while fetching huge data from database in wso2

Tags: pagination, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I have a requirement where I have to handle more than 1000 records from DB and implement pagination for display those results in wso2.

I need suggestions.

Comment: Can you be more specific in your requirement,First can you tell how is the code flow happening, is it from esb to dss or dss to esb,If it is from esb then do you want the request to go to dss in pagination form?

Comment: lets say I have more than one million records.I ll have to fetch from database and expose as an api.So for that I ll have to handle streaming and pagination like how many records for a page , etc.. I created a dss service and calling it as an end point in esb. Its buffering and getting memory exception.

Comment: How are you planning to expose the API? Are you planning to send response to the client everything at one shot,say if you have 1000 records in DB so do you want to display all the records at one go?

Comment: yes.I have to expose everything all ...

Comment: As far as i know it is a performance impact and memory will be exhausted as and when records grow in DB, No wonder why you were getting memory exception.So I don't think you can expose a API which will display all the records from DB

Comment: any alternate solution then?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the alternate solution is by using batch processing withing ESB, you first create a query in DSS which would take start and end records like below `SELECT * from [table_name] where between :Start AND :End`
you can fetch the start and end date from a file, so that it is configurable in UAT and production. for example start = 1, end = 100 and increment = 100.
Now once you run the API in first iteration it will fetch 100 records which will be sent to the calling system, then increment it by 100 so your start will be 101 and end will be 200.
You need to keep doing this until there is empty response from DSS.

Comment: where i should increment the result using and increment = 100. Because as per your suggestion I will get 100 records as  output. could you explain in better way.

Comment: In ESB there is local entries, you can add an XML there similar to the format <FetchRecordxmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
      <Start>1</Start>
      <End>100</End>
      <Increment>100</Increment>
   </FetchRecord>, Now you need to read this from you sequence and then call DSS, once you get the record then you need to increment it

Comment: I have one more idea. Can i store all data in file using vfs.

Comment: Yes you can first call in batch and then use VFS but how will you display entire data from VFS to the calling system?

Comment: I ll have to iterate and call their endpoint. But its not the way I am thinking.

Comment: How can you iterate on wso2 DSS? You require an incoming request on which you can iterate, here you are fetching the data from DB and then sending it to another system

Comment: Once calling dss end point data will be there in esb run time. 
From there u will have to iterate...

Comment: If you are planning to fetch entire records from DSS and then use iterate then prepare for ESB to crash, as once record increases in DB then there are high chance that ESB heap memory will be exhausted and it will eventually crash,However you can try your approach for 2000-3000 records and then you can see the impact

Comment: For 3000 records I am able to get with out any issues.

Comment: Good, but can you let me know are you running only you API or even others are testing their API, i mean is it a stand alone system or development system where you are testing

Comment: I am running on my local machine...I tried with sample data.

Comment: You can try running the same in development server and check if there is performance impact

Comment: As per my knowledge it's not advisable to split or iterate 3000-4000+ records in ESB

Comment: yes. I tried enriching the content of response to a body and then responded.It works fine.